# Atmosphere Websocket support onHandshake event for WebSocketEventListenerAdapter

Tags: jetty, netty, dropwizard, atmosphere

WebSocketEventListenerAdapter gives you the option to implement the onHandshake event:

```
@Override
public void onHandshake(WebSocketEvent event) {
    LOG.debug("{}", event);
}
```

I need to do some third party operations during handshake but it doesn't seem to work

How is it possible with Atmosphere to trigger some actions during handshake and interrupt handshake if for example the client should not connect?

I do this on the onOpen event but I want to avoid it since the client first connects and then disconnects back if according to my logic I call AtmosphereResource.close() to close the connection.

I'm currently using Atmosphere with dropwizard (that means jetty), following some examples like so: https://github.com/mgutz/dropwizard-atmosphere

There is also an implementation with Netty called [netosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/nettosphere) is it possible to implement onHandshake event?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work. Which server are you using? let's have the discussion on the mailing list as some server may not be supported. But for sure it will works with nettosphere.

https://groups.google.com/group/atmosphere-framework?pli=1